# I have problem when i try to generate a signed apk from Flutter code

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I have problem when i try to generate a signed apk from Flutter code.
Here is my problem.

```
[Fatal Error] lifecycle-runtime-2.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Element type "depende" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

Comment: check lifecycle-runtime-2.0.0.pom:2:1 file if the ending tags are finished correctly.

Comment: where to find it. sorry but i am new i just boguht a codecanyon code.

Comment: If you bought the code and it doesn't run, you should ask for support from the developer first.

Answer (score 0):

In the project-level build Gradle.
Change

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
       google()

   }
```

to

```
buildscript {
      repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
   }
```

and delete the folders from the android folder

```
.gradle\caches
// go to the folder where your project is located and delete
.gradle
.idea
all iml files
```

if the build folder is located in the app folder delete it.

Comment: same problem  and even when i create a new flutter app same problem

Comment: Run ```flutter doctor --stacktrace``` and share the report